# Printing PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have the following php script which returns a string of numbers with commas separating them:

```
<?php include "printqueryrows.php"; ?>
```

returns

```
 2.00 , 1.00 , 21.16 , 6.75 , 6.00 , 6.25 , 3.00 ,
```

I have a javascript chart creator that requires the data in the following format:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ...
                {
                name: 'London',
                data: [2.00 , 1.00 , 21.16 , 6.75 , 6.00 , 6.25 , 3.00 , ]
              }
</script>
```

In order to include the results from the php file in the data field (so that it prints out the numbers, separated by commas, I use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ...
    data: [<?php include "printqueryrows.php"; ?>]
</script>
```

However, this is not printing the data. If I do this line individually in another script, the data prints. But it doesn't print when I try to print it into this javascript file. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're just putting `data: etc` without curly brackets?

Comment: Does the HTML-File with the javascript-code have the correct file extension? (.php)

Comment: Try setting  `var queryrows = <?php include "printqueryrows.php"; ?>;` in a script tag. Then after put either `alert(queryrows);` or `console.log(queryrows)` to check the value is being set correctly

Comment: Please be aware that echoing into JavaScript context may make your application vulnerable to XSS attacks if any of the data is user-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the file that contains your Javascript is *itself* a PHP script - make sure it ends in `.php`. If you're not sure if it's worked, check the source of the resulting web page. It should not contain `<?php` anywhere in the browser-side source.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had some extra <?php in there

Answer (score 0):

Check two things :

1. Make sure that JS is embedded in a file with .php extension
2. Make sure that your printqueryrows.php does :

   echo "2.00 , 1.00 , 21.16 , 6.75 , 6.00 , 6.25 , 3.00 , ";